Запятая перед «и прежде всего» нужна ли?
Был подписан ряд важных соглашений в различных сферах(?) и прежде всего в сфере торговли.

Запятая нужна:
Был подписан ряд важных соглашений в различных сферах, и прежде всего в сфере торговли.
Пояснение
Обстоятельственный оборот  "и прежде всего в сфере торговли" включено в уже названное обстоятельство "в различных сферах" (значение в том числе), поэтому оборот обособляется.
Союз И присоединительный, а не соединительный. Но при дополнительном значении оборота  союз И  может быть соединительным, и такие варианты есть в Карте слов.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Что союз присоединительный, это надо как-то ДОКАЗАТЬ. Содержит дополнительные пояснения? А почему они дополнительные? С этим союзом И всё очень непросто) Здесь именно что МНОЖЕСТВО надо рассматривать — входит ли новый член в это множество или дополняет его? А потом уж конкретизировать значение.
КОНКРЕТИКА ЖЕ сочетания  определяется семантикой слов (в первую очередь, сначала, как самое важное, самое главное, раньше чего-либо другого, вначале и т.д.), да только эта семантика не зависит от вида союза И (соединительный или присоединительный). Вот это важно!
Карта слов
Они – рабы не только класса буржуазии, буржуазного государства, ежедневно и ежечасно порабощает их машина, надсмотрщик и прежде всего сам отдельный буржуа-фабрикант. Карл Генрих Маркс, Манифест коммунистической партии. Принципы коммунизма.
У Карла Маркса соединительный союз)
Осознанность стала очень популярной практикой в лечебных центрах, компаниях, учебных аудиториях, мастерских и прежде всего в исследовательских лабораториях по всему миру.
Марат Рашитович Шаехов, Школа ценностей, 2022
Серьёзное внимание в годы войны уделялось освещению вопросов истории психологии и прежде всего отечественной психологической мысли.
Коллектив авторов, Психологическая наука в России XX столетия: проблемы теории и истории, 1997

● Союз и в этом предложении является присоединительным.

Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину или в конец предложения, отделяются или выделяются запятыми (реже — тире).

● Наречное выражение прежде всего здесь имеет такое значение:
в первую очередь, сначала (как самое важное, самое главное), раньше чего-либо другого, вначале.
Думаю, что значение "в том числе" тут не подходит.
● Возможная пунктуация (в зависимости от контекста и расставленных акцентов)
• С запятой (самый частотный):
Был подписан ряд важных соглашений в различных сферах, и прежде всего в сфере торговли.
Пример:
Повторяем, этот процесс развертывается главным образом в диалогах, и прежде всего в диалогах со Смердяковым (М. М. Бахтин).
• С тире:
...ряд важных соглашений в различных сферах — и прежде всего в сфере торговли.
Пример:
Будущее все сильнее растворялось в прошлых свершениях — и прежде всего в той самой победе над Гитлером... ("Русский репортер").
• С запятой и тире:
...ряд важных соглашений в различных сферах, и прежде всего — в сфере торговли.
Примеры:
Я проклинал себя, свою память, свою недавнюю болезнь, которая, как всегда, была виновата во всех моих бедах, и прежде всего — в рассеянности (К. Г. Паустовский).
Такое глубокое личностное общение, в котором вырабатываются взгляды, принципы, ценности, идет во всех первичных группах, и прежде всего — в семье (В. Голофаст. "Знание ― сила").

Объяснение некорректное. Нет грамматического доказательства того, что союз присоединительный. Просто слова и примеры мало что значат. Есть примеры того, где И ПРЕЖДЕ ВСЕГО имеет соединительное значение. Эти варианты надо было сравнить. Минус от меня за минусовку моего ответа. Это не метод доказаельства

Согласна, что минусовка — не метод доказательства. Но использовали эту функцию именно Вы. // А я к вашему ответу вообще не прикасалась.

Простите, это я напортачил, вчера второпях плюсы расставлял, а сегодня смотрю, минус горит :)) Исправил.

Приветствую, Саша! Извинения — это, конечно, хорошо. Не поняла, правда, что и как ты исправил.

Я поменял минус на плюс у ответа Sharon.

Ну да, ну да... Здорово. Только я осталась наказанной. Не виноватая я!..

Римма, нужно внести какое-нибудь изменение в ответ, тогда можно будет снять минус.

@Sharon Вы же уберёте минус?
